# Applying for jobs outside academia: when and what kind of jobs are out there?

Tags: phd, job-search, soft-skills

I am at the end of my PhD. I am considering switching to the private sector and find a job in some company. There are two main questions I did not find an answer yet:

1. Is there some professional profile requiring the abstract level of expertise acquired during a three years PhD project, independently from the specific field of research? I can see how the soft-skills of problem solving, project management, team-work, that most of PhD have to acquire in order to finish their studies can be spent outside academia. Yet, I am not aware of the terminology, and thus I am not able to find this answer by myself. All help is highly appreciated.
2. Is the end of a PhD the optimal time to do this passage from academia to private sector? Is a post-doc only an unnecessary step further from the employer point of view?

Despite I come from bio-medical research (behvioral neuroscience), I am especially looking for an answer that does not take in consideration the specific background of the PhD.

I hope I got my first question on this community right, and I didn´t waste anyone's time.

Comment: I am voting to close this as too broad. I hold in my hands a 360-page brochure listing mostly such fields of activity.

Comment: See [Career for a mathematician outside academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12239/career-for-a-mathematician-outside-academia), [Non-academic positions after PhD in computer science](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/37606/non-academic-positions-after-phd-in-computer-science), [Non academic career for PhD in Biology](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/54509/non-academic-career-for-phd-in-biology)

Comment: Re: when, see [Leaving PhD program to apply for industry job - better to apply while still officially enrolled?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/25770/leaving-phd-program-to-apply-for-industry-job-better-to-apply-while-still-offi), [Applying for industry jobs: how early do you submit job applications?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/59301/applying-for-industry-jobs-how-early-do-you-submit-job-applications)

Comment: And regarding the postdoc thing, see [Is postdoc experience valued by industry?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/60274/is-postdoc-experience-valued-by-industry), [Will taking a post-doc position harm my future chances in industry?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20846/will-taking-a-post-doc-position-harm-my-future-chances-in-industry)

Comment: Also see [What are the potential pitfalls of having a PhD?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11149/what-are-the-potential-pitfalls-of-having-a-phd)

Comment: In brief and in general: 1) No. 2) Yes, but bear in mind that you can't go back from industry to academia.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I will check the already existing questions you posted as relevant. I have been suggested elsewhere to look for jobs in counseling agencies. I have been told they often require some of the skills I listed (problem solving attitude, presentations skills, etc.) without requiring a specific background (that can be acquired during an internship period).